# Android: Pending Intent of Notification shall be used just once

Tags: android, notifications, launcher, android-pendingintent

I've a problem which seems strange to me. I've different notifications that are thrown when an alarm goes off. Each notification has an pendingIntent that contains a serializable object. As I am working with fragments, every pendingIntent is sent to the same activity, namely the main activity. Depending on the contained object in the pendingIntent, another fragment is shown. This works perfect. The problem is if I am closing the app and open it again via the launcher icon, not the defined main fragment but the previous fragment (that has been created from the notification) is shown. As I've observed it in Logcat, it seems to be that the MainActivity that is started when i click on the launcher icon reads still the pendingIntent. Isn't the pendingIntent deleted after having been used? I've created the pendingIntent with the FLAG_ONE_SHOT....
I would be grateful for help!

Comment: did you check if your MainActivity is being recreated? From what you mentioned above, it appears it is not, which is the reason why it is showing the last-shown fragment (from notification)

Comment: that's right, it is not recreated and it would be okay, if the last shown fragment would be the one that is shown if restarting the app... The problem is that the fragment from the notification is not the last shown one before i close the app....and nevertheless this fragment is shown when clicking on the launcher icon again.

Comment: Did you had any pending notifications in the notification bar when you started the app from launcher? If yes, can you try clearing the notifications in the onCreate() of the MainActivity(). So that the PendingIntents are no longer valid.

Comment: Thank you for your help....I resolved it now by using getIntent().removeExtra(...);